# Moving Objects Help

Tags: java, android

I want to know how is it possible,I could have an Object drawn  at a certain point and move to the point that is touched on the screen. I am trying to use it for my game where when the user touches on the screen, the gun fires from the position of the player, but the player is stationary.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.

Is there a visual graphic of some sort that shows where every plot is on android.

Comment: I am not trying to make a drag and drop. The player icon is at PointA and never moves. The attacking sprites move towards him. And I am trying to get it to where when you touch on the screen it sends a bullet to that location. But the bullet isn't drawn until you touch the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what kind of library you're using to draw all of your things, but that basically doesn't matter since you only need to know two things in order to do this:

Without going into specifics on vector geometry:
1. You need to calculate the direction (x and y component) that the projectile moves in depending on your mouses position. You get this direction by simply subtracting the position of the mouse from the position of the player:

```
//x component of direction
float direction_x = mousePosition.x - playerPosition.x;
//y component of direction
float direction_y = mousePosition.y - playerPosition.y;
```

In order to just get a direction instead of adding a velocity component to this vector, you need to normalize it (so it has a length of 1):

```
float length =(float) Math.sqrt(direction_x*direction_x + direction_y*direction_y);
direction_x /= length;
direction_y /= length;
```

You then need to update the projectiles position by adding the direction_x and direction_y components to it, multiplied by the speed that you want the projectile to have (This process is called linear interpolation, by the way):

```
projectile_x += direction_x*speed;
projectile_y += direction_y*speed;
```

If you have some way of measuring the time between two frames, the speed variable should depend on the elapsed time between those frames, in order to create smooth movements on different platforms.

Comment: @heishe you don't need to create HTML tags to handle code. Just select the code and hit the "code sample" button (or add 4 spaces to each line by yourself)

Comment: Thanks! I was already wondering why it was so complicated to do. I looked through the FAQ and didn't find anything, so thank you very much :)

Comment: Would I put that bit into my bullet class or inside of my thread.

Comment: Good question. Personally, I'd give my bullet the ability to calculate how it moves to the target. More specifically, when I create the bullet, I'd hand it over a target in the cconstructor, then give the class a method "update()" which I call every frame, which calculates how much it needs to move.

Comment: I have a bullet class, its not a good one but it does have a update method. I am trying to figure out if I would implement your example in the bullet class its self or in the gameloop thread.

Comment: You can use it in your bullet class. You can pretty much copy and paste my code into your update method, and replace the names with whatever they're named in your game.